# jQuery variable within string, quotes within quotes

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(".container").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)'onClick='showField('"+data.name+"','"+data.text+"');'>Edit</a>");
```

Which is outputting (notice the quote problem before the `4` and before the `>edit`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showField("4','school_type');'>Edit</a>
```

When it should be outputting:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showField('4','school_type');">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try `\"` instead of `'` in `onClick`:

```
$(".container").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick=\"showField('"+data.name+"','"+data.text+"');\">Edit</a>");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape your `"`s with `\`

```
$(".container").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='showField(\""+data.name+"\",\""+data.text+"\");'>Edit</a>");
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yFf55/1/)

Comment: That was my first guess too, but it results in the exact same output as the original.

Comment: Check out [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yFf55/1/). It displays properly.

Comment: Hmm I dont know, its just not working for me. @mgraph 's answer did the trick, i guess it was the outer " being intercepted by the inner ones that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although this reply is coming at a late hour, however you can also achieve what you want using something like this:

```
    var element = '<p class = ' + '"capitals"' + '> This is a new paragraph</p>'
    $(".container").append(element);
```

If you print the above code to debug console the following output will be printed:

```
     <p class = "capitals">This is a new paragraph</p>
```

You can use double and single quotes combined togther like this `'""'` to print out double quotes. Another Example:

```
        var doublequotedtext = '"Hello"'; 
        debug.print(doublequotedtext);
```

so applying the above to your code:

```
       var element = '<a href = ' + '"javascript:void(0)"' + 'onClick = ' + '"showField(data.name,data.text);"' + '>Edit</a>'
       $(".container").append(element);
```